# pcie SR-IOV driver howto

Tags: virtualization, linux-networking, virtual-machines, linux-kernel, drivers

I am trying to know how linux PCIE NIC SR-IOV work.
I am using a Unbuntu with Intel 82599 NIC as a host. Under NIC driver directory(ixgbe) in linux Kernel, there is a file named "ixgbe_sriov.c".
I know this file may drive to make some VFs which respectively show some PCIE devices to user.
My questions is "if i install another ubuntu as a guest OS on my host,what kind of NIC driver  does the guest OS use? Still the 82599 ixbge driver?“
Anybody know it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When you pass through a SR-IOV virtual function to your guest OS, it sees the same type of NIC as on the host and uses the same driver.

You can read the Red Hat Enterprise Linux documentation on SR-IOV for complete details on [how to set up SR-IOV with KVM](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/virtualization_deployment_and_administration_guide/sect-pci_devices-pci_passthrough). About 99% of this is the same regardless of Linux distribution.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Michael. But from the article you linked , it clearly point out that VF and PF in SR-IOV mod use different driver.  To Intel 82599 card , for example, as a PF in host OS it use ixgbe drive while as VF in guset OS it use ixgbevf driver.